# Methods inside enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration

In Java, it's possible to have methods inside an enum.

Is there such possibility in C# or is it just a string collection and that's it?

I tried to override `ToString()` but it does not compile. Does someone have a simple code sample?

Comment: I don't think you can have methods inside an Enum in C#. What are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to get Java behavior and encapsulate close logic to Enums. anyway I see from the answers it is not possible - I'll implement extensions.

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You can write [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method) for enum types:

```
enum Stuff
{
    Thing1,
    Thing2
}

static class StuffMethods
{

    public static String GetString(this Stuff s1)
    {
        switch (s1)
        {
            case Stuff.Thing1:
                return "Yeah!";
            case Stuff.Thing2:
                return "Okay!";
            default:
                return "What?!";
        }
    }
}

class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stuff thing = Stuff.Thing1;
        String str = thing.GetString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You can write an extension method for your enum:

[How to: Create a New Method for an Enumeration (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383974.aspx)

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use the [Enumeration Class](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/) created by **Jimmy Bogard**.

Basically, you must create a class that inherits from his `Enumeration`. Example:

```
public class EmployeeType : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly EmployeeType Manager 
        = new EmployeeType(0, "Manager");
    public static readonly EmployeeType Servant 
        = new EmployeeType(1, "Servant");
    public static readonly EmployeeType Assistant
        = new EmployeeType(2, "Assistant to the Regional Manager");

    private EmployeeType() { }
    private EmployeeType(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }

    // Your method...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{value} - {displayName}!";
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like an enum, with the possibility to put methods inside it (among another things):

```
EmployeeType.Manager.ToString();
//0 - Manager
EmployeeType.Servant.ToString();
//1 - Servant
EmployeeType.Assistant.ToString();
//2 - Assistant to the Regional Manager
```

*You can download it with [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Enumeration/).*

Although this implementation is not native in the language, the syntax (construction and usage) is pretty close to languages that implement enums natively better than C# ([Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html) for example).

Comment: A downside with this is that the enum values no longer count as a constants.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You can create a class, then add a bunch of properties to the class to *somewhat* emulate an enum, but thats *not really the same thing*.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyString1 { get{ return "one";} }
    public string MyString2 { get{ return "two";} }
    public string MyString3 { get{ return "three";} }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

A better pattern would be to put your methods in a class separate from your emum.

Comment: An extension of this is actually a good practice: instead of properties returning strings, you can return an instance of MyClass that stores a text value inside it. Practically this would be equivalent to Java's enums. It is suggested that enum classes - such as your suggestion with some tweaks - are preferred to the C# enum type.

Answer (score 1):

Since I came across, and needed the exact opposite of enum to string, here is a Generic solution:

```
static class EnumExtensions {
    public static T GetEnum<T>(this string itemName) {
        return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), itemName, true);
    }
}
```

This also ignores case and is very handy for parsing REST-Response to your enum to obtain more type safety.
Hopefully it helps someone

Answer (score -9):

C# Does not allow use of methods in enumerators as it is not a class based principle, but rather an 2 dimensional array with a string and value.

Use of classes is highly discouraged by Microsoft in this case, use (data)struct(ures) instead; The STRUCT is intended as a light class for data and its handlers and can handle functions just fine. C# and its compiler don't have the tracking and efficiency capabilities as one knows from JAVA, where the more times a certain class / method is used the faster it runs and its use becomes 'anticipated'. C# simply doesn't have that, so to differentiate, use STRUCT instead of CLASS.

Comment: Seven down votes without a single comment to explain what's supposed to be wrong with this answer? C'mon guys...

Comment: Is the all the information provided in this post wrong?

Comment: This part is true: C# Does not allow use of methods in enumerators.  I'm not sure if the reasoning is correct though, and the second paragraph seems completely irrelevant to the question.  If there's a way to use a struct to simulate an enum with behaviour, providing an example would be best.

Comment: I think the implications are fairly clear here. Do not replace an enum (which is a value type) with a class (which is a reference type) just to add methods, since structs also can have methods and are also value types.