# C# enum with abstract methods

Tags: c#, enums

I'm a Java developer, making a transition to working in C#. I'm familiar with the following pattern -- abstract method or interface implemented by each `Enum` member -- in Java:

```
public enum Animal {
    CAT {
        public String makeNoise() { return "meow!"; }
    },
    DOG {
        public String makeNoise() { return "woof!"; }
    };

    public abstract String makeNoise();
}
```

and I am wondering if (a) this pattern is possible in C# and (b) whether this is a Csharpy (do people say  that?) thing to do. (I don't have my ide setup yet, and concede I should be able to try this out on my own. But it is interesting that I have had a hard time finding an example of this pattern for C# on the internet). Thanks!

Comment: You can't add methods to C# enums at all. They are "simply" an association of names to numeric values (and a few conversion rules to try to avoid silly mistakes in using them)

Comment: Use extension methods.

Comment: A: Nope, sadly not. You can however use [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5985710/9363973) answer.

B: Nope, as it is not possible, this isn't "Csharpy", or "idiomatic" C# what most people call it, the idiomatic way of doing this is by using extension methods

Comment: @theraot yeah, I guess that  link does address this question. Thanks!